# IBM MQ getCurrentDepth requires accessQueue

Tags: java, ibm-mq, depth

When I want to get mq depth, and I use `getCurrentDepth` I notice it doesn't work on a stored/cached mq queue object. 
I need a 'fresh' queue object and I need to do an `accessQueue` method call, get the queue and the use the `getCurrentDepth` method on that object. Otherwise, the depth is always zero.

I didn't find any open questions/documentation around this behavior.

I'm using the MQ client for java version 7.0 on linux.
My open options are: MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
and I use an SSL connection.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> I notice it doesn't work on a stored/cached mq queue object.

There is no such thing as stored/cached MQ queue object.  The queue types are: local, remote, alias cluster.

> I need a 'fresh' queue object

There is no such concept of fresh (refresh) the queue object.

The getCurrentDepth method belongs to the MQQueue class.  Therefore, you need to access the queue using the accessQueue method of the MQQueueManager class.

Finally, there should NEVER be a need to use the getCurrentDepth method in an MQ application.  You either get a single message or loop until an MQException is thrown with MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE (2033) reason code.

Comment: mQueue = queueManager.accessQueue(aQueueName, aOptions, null, null, null); <\br>
int depth = mQueue.getCurrentDepth(); <-- correct result <\br>
depth = mQueue.getCurrentDepth();  <-- zero - even when no one has picked up the message from the queue. This method seems to run fine only for the first time.    if we do a accessQueue again, then the method works fine again for 1 time.

Comment: This is a few years too late, but could you explain why there should NEVER be a reason to use getCurrentDepth? I have SpringBoot Jms Application that connects and reads from a MQ Queue, but I won't get an MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE (2033), assuming it gets caught somewhere in Spring, so my listener ends up hanging and waits for more messages. My solution was to just call getCurrentDepth every so often and when zero I can finally terminate. Never had an issue, but I'd love to hear why it could be.

Comment: 1st, it sounds like you used the wrong component listener - don't use one that loops forever when that is not what you require.  2nd, messages that are part of a transaction but have not been committed will be include in the 'Current Depth' count.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is that you call accessQueue and then call getCurrentDepth on the returned MQQueue object and it returns the expected value. Then, at some point later, you call getCurrentDepth() on the same MQQueue object and it returns zero (unexpected).

I haven't seen that behaviour before and it isn't what is expected. If the MQQueue object was 'stale' then you should get an MQException thrown from the getCurrentDepth method, and I assume that is not happening.

Have you verified that the depth is what you expect it to be at the time i.e. maybe another application has removed the messages or a transaction has rolled back for example.